# Linked List clear list function

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, circular-list

I am currently working on a project, I have a circular doubly linked list which includes 2 integers as `quantity` and `price`, and 1 string as `itemName`. Here is my struct for node:

```
struct node {
        int quantity, price;
        string itemName;
        node * next;
        node * prev;
        node (int x = 0, int y = 0, string str = "", node * p = NULL, node * r = NULL): quantity(x), price(y), itemName(str), next(p), prev(r){}
    };
```

I am currently doing well, I did my `addSorted` function, print list function etc, and they work great. I have a problem about my `clearList` function. As I do my "new node" assignment in my addItem function, I can't delete nodes in my clearList function. Here is my clearList function:

```
void clear(node * head){
        if (head == NULL) {
            cout << "List is empty." << endl;
        }
        else {
            node * ptr = head->next;
            while(ptr != head)
            {
                ptr = head;
                head = head->next;
                delete ptr;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am having an error like this:

> main(21281,0x100098600) malloc: *** error for object 0x103033080: pointer being freed was not allocated
> main(21281,0x100098600) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

What is the problem, and how can I delete the nodes that I created in another function? How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Please try to create a proper [mre], and [edit] your question to show it.

Answer (score 1):

Think about your logic here

```
       node * ptr = head->next;
        while(ptr != head)
        {
            ptr = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete ptr;
        }
```

`while (ptr != head)` implies that in the while loop `ptr` does equal `head` but the very next line says `ptr = head;` A sure sign that you were confused when writing this code.

Another issue is that when all the nodes have been deleted you want to end up with `head` equal to NULL but your code doesn't do that.

Here's my effort

```
if (head == NULL) {
    cout << "List is empty." << endl;
}
else {
    node* n = head;
    do
    {
        node* next = n->next;
        delete n;
        n = next;
    }
    while (n != head);
    head = NULL;
}
```

Completely untested, use with caution.

Comment: Thank you so much, I clearly understood that I couldn't think of the state after the clear process. It definitely works now. Thank you so much!

Comment: There's no point in doing `head = NULL;`; the pointer is passed by value... Furthermore you should be using `nullptr` instead of `NULL` in C++...

Comment: @fabian Both good points